# Use of ci in pointplot

Tags: python, seaborn

I am using factorplot in seaborn. According to the documentation, it is possible to plot standard deviations in place of 95% confidence intervals by using argument ci= "sd". However, when I am trying to use it, I always obtain the error:
unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'

Any clues about it?

Thanks!

Comment: Which version of seaborn are you using?

Comment: @JonathanPorter 0.7.1

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [What's new section of seaborn version 0.8.0](http://seaborn.pydata.org/whatsnew.html):

> Added the ability to use error bars to show standard deviations rather than bootstrap confidence intervals in most statistical functions by putting `ci="sd"`.

It would be self explanatory that versions prior to 0.8.0 do not have this option.